# New-PSSession Cmdlet using Oauth credentials

Tags: powershell, session, oauth, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to create a **`New-PSSession`** using an **access token (Oauth)** and not a default credentials.

Is it possible?

According to [***documentation***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession#-authentication), these are the authentications types:

- Default
- Basic
- Credssp
- Digest
- Kerberos
- Negotiate
- NegotiateWithImplicitCredential

Thanks!

Comment: Please add an example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`New-PSSession` connects with PS Remoting (WinRM) which does not support OAuth authentication. You can supply a `PSCredential` object used to get that OAuth token instead, if any.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I'm not sure I understand. Can you please add a code example? I'm try to run the following: 1.  $UserCredential = Get-Credential
2.  $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
3.  Import-PSSession $Session
But without Credential